# Laravel - Run a method on multiple different processes

Tags: php, asynchronous, process, laravel-5

I have a method that is going to gather data from various APIs for many users. Right now, it does it only `sequentialy`, one user after another. The actual traffic produced by those API calls is very low, so I wondered, how could I process, say, `5 users at a time`. Multiple processes of Laravel came to mind, but upon closer inspection it turned out, that Laravel doesn't seem to have faculties for that.

I found a `Symphony` component called `The Process Component`, that could do the job, probably.

My question is: has anyone done something similar? Is there a better solution than using that package? Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend adding this task to a queue and assign multiple queue workers to work on the jobs

Comment: Thank you for the comment! One question still remains: are those, say, 10 workers, going to perform the Jobs assigned to them simultaneously? Is it threaded, or just a multiprocessed thing?